# Field ‘@’ has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, initialization

Im using some code from a tutorial but putting it in my own app. I cant figure out the next warning and how to solve:

LateInitializationError: Field ‘_durationRemaining@585382383’ has not been initialized.

The code(piece of the whole code) where this error is from is:

```
late MapBoxNavigation _directions;
  late MapBoxOptions _options;

  bool _isMultipleStop = false;
  late double _distanceRemaining, _durationRemaining;
  late MapBoxNavigationViewController _controller;
  bool _routeBuilt = false;
  bool _isNavigating = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
   initialize();
  }
```

The error is about the rule:

late double _distanceRemaining, _durationRemaining;

Am i doing something wrong? Maybe because i have 2 fields behind the late double and not the right way?

If i delete the Late in front of double, then get this errors:

lib/main.dart:42:10: Error: Field ‘_distanceRemaining’ should be initialized because its type ‘double’ doesn’t allow null.
double _distanceRemaining, _durationRemaining;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/main.dart:42:30: Error: Field ‘_durationRemaining’ should be initialized because its type ‘double’ doesn’t allow null.
double _distanceRemaining, _durationRemaining;

Answer (score 0):

When defining any variable as `late`, it must be initialized with the specified type before accessing it. In your case, it should be initialized in the `initState()` function. If you don't want to use the `late` keyword, you could make your variable nullable by using the `?` operator.
For Eg

```
double? _distanceRemaining, _durationRemaining;
```

This would make your `double` variable nullable meaning it could accept null values.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If I do that I get:
264:60: Error: Operator '/' cannot be called on 'double?' because it is potentially null.
? "${(_durationRemaining / 60).toStringAsFixed(0)} minutes"
272:60: Error: Operator '*' cannot be called on 'double?' because it is potentially null.
? "${(_distanceRemaining * 0.000621371).toStringAsFixed(1)} miles"

The code there is:

```
? "${(_durationRemaining / 60).toStringAsFixed(0)} minutes"
```

```
? "${(_distanceRemaining * 0.000621371).toStringAsFixed(1)} miles"
```

I have to change something there also I guess. Because there it cant be null?

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is nullable, you are restricted to using the normal operations and function calls that can be used on non-nullable variables.
For eg

```
double? _durationRemaining;
var x = _durationRemaing + 10;
```

You cannot do this operation because `_durationRemaing` can be null. For this, you can use the `??` operator, which checks whether the variable is null or not.

```
var x = (_durationRemaing ?? 0) + 10;
```

This means that if the variable is null use 0 as the value. So you have to use the `??` operator in your code mentioned above.

Comment: I go to try and learn:

I get again the error:
LateInitializationError: Field '_durationRemaining@585382383' has not been initialized.
if I place ?? 0 in front of the / 60 and in front of the other * 0.xxx

So have to figure out the good way but thanks for helping so far :)